# nvd3 scatterplot: labels on bullets

Tags: plot, nvd3.js

I have a requirement that the bullets on a specific implementation of a scatterplot needs to have labels next to them, however, it is known that many of the datapoints in the set are identical or very close to one another, so if I were to set labels on a fixed coordinate relative to the bullet, the labels would stack on top of eachother and not be readable.

I want to implement this so that the labels will give way for eachother - moving around, so they don't overlap - and I am thinking that this is a common enough idea that some approach already exists, but I have no idea what to search for. Does this concept have a name?

I would ofcource appreciate an implementation example, but that is not the most important thing. I am sure I can solve it myself, but I'd rather not reinvent something that someone else has already done better.

[image]

The image above displays examples of bullets on top of and close to each other

Comment: Practically it is not a good idea to have labels around the scatter points as points increases overlapping of text and point will make things clumsy. I would prefer having a tooltip instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding inspiration in [Simulated Annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing).

My solution looks like this

```
/**
 * Implements an algorithm for placing labels on a chart in a way so that they
 * do not overlap as much.
 * The approach is inspired by Simulated Annealing
 * (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing)
 */
export class Placer {
    private knownPositions: Coordinate[];
    private START_RADIUS = 20;
    private RUNS = 15;
    private ORIGIN_WEIGHT = 2;

    constructor() {
        this.knownPositions = []
    }

    /**
     * Get a good spot to place the object.
     *
     * Given a start coordinate, this method tries to find the best place
     * that is close to that point but not too close to other known points.
     *
     * @param {Coordinate} coordinate
     * @returns {Coordinate}
     */
    getPlacement(coordinate: Coordinate) : Coordinate {
        let radius = this.START_RADIUS;
        let lastPosition = coordinate;
        let lastScore = 0;
        while (radius > 0) {
            const newPosition = this.getRandomPosition(coordinate, radius);
            const newScore = this.getScore(newPosition, coordinate);
            if (newScore > lastScore) {
                lastPosition = newPosition;
                lastScore = newScore;
            }
            radius -= this.START_RADIUS / this.RUNS;
        }
        this.knownPositions.push(lastPosition);
        return lastPosition;
    }

    /**
     * Return a random point on the radius around the position
     *
     * @param {Coordinate} position Center point
     * @param {number} radius Distance from `position` to find a point
     * @returns {Coordinate} A random point `radius` distance away from
     *     `position`
     */
    private getRandomPosition(position: Coordinate, radius:number) : Coordinate {
        const randomRotation = radians(Math.random() * 360);
        const xOffset = Math.cos(randomRotation) * radius;
        const yOffset = Math.sin(randomRotation) * radius;
        return {
            x: position.x + xOffset,
            y: position.y + yOffset,
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a number score of a position. The further away it is from any
     * other known point, the better the score (bigger number), however, it
     * suffers a subtraction in score the further away it gets from its origin
     * point.
     *
     * @param {Coordinate} position The position to score
     * @param {Coordinate} origin The initial position before looking for
     *     better ones
     * @returns {number} The representation of the score
     */
    private getScore(position: Coordinate, origin: Coordinate) : number {
        let closest: number = null;
        this.knownPositions.forEach((knownPosition) => {
            const distance = Math.abs(Math.sqrt(
                Math.pow(knownPosition.x - position.x, 2) +
                Math.pow(knownPosition.y - position.y, 2)
            ));
            if (closest === null || distance < closest) {
                closest = distance;
            }
        });
        const distancetoOrigin = Math.abs(Math.sqrt(
            Math.pow(origin.x - position.x, 2) +
            Math.pow(origin.y - position.y, 2)
        ));
        return closest - (distancetoOrigin / this.ORIGIN_WEIGHT);
    }
}
```

There is room for improvement in the `getScore` method, but the results are good enough for my case.

Basically, all points try to move to a random position in a given radius and sees if that position is "better" than the original. The algorithm keeps doing that for a smaller and smaller radius until radius = 0.

The class keeps track of all known points, so that when you try to place point number two, the scoring can account for the presence of point number one.